# How can i open an md-card element as a lightbox and how can i give it a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am using **md-card** directive of angular material, as you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXtRJ.png) each md-card has a *picture, a title, a price and a decription*.

What i want to do is to make the **picture clickable** and if somebody clicks on it a **lightbox opens** showing the picture, the description, the price, etc .. and the browser url bar should show a link of that lightbox

I also want to add a **facebook share button** next to **Contact** and **Admin** buttons and if somebody clicks on it, the md-card element will be shared on facebook, so when somebody clicks on the shared link on facebook, the lightbox of that md-card opens

Please help me do that, thank you